# How to modify variable values in .dtsx file without applying an executable code or executing the package file

Tags: xml, ssis

Is there a simple way to modify the value of a variable defined in a SSIS .dtsx package file (XML format) without using an executable like msxsl.exe or a customized equivalent?  The file needs to be updated before it is then copied using dtutil to MSDB of Integration Services.  I know I can update the variable using dtexec, but that then runs the package file, which I do not want to do at this point.

I have a .dtsx package file created in Visual Studio 2010 that needs to be deployed to client server machines locally running SQL Server 2012.  I do not know the names of their servers and this information must be updated into a variable in the .dtsx package file when it arrives, and it is updated by somebody onsite.  I do not have access to the client servers and they will not permit me to send them executable files.  The variable(s) that need to be updated can be a server name (not necessarily the server on which the package is installed, otherwise would use System::MachineName variable), database name or something else unique to the site.  My plan is to use a batch file running in the Command Prompt to perform the updates and prompt the user to provide the values for parameters that will then be passed on to the .dtsx file.  I cannot use PowerShell because this varies from client to client.  Once the batch scripts are run, which updates the .dtsx file and copies the update to Integration Services, the .dtsx file and all temporary scripts are removed.

For example, I am applying Error Handling in the SSIS package and wish to send an email alert using the email address defined in a user variable called EmailAlert.  The person who receives the alert will differ from one client site to the next.  The variable looks like the following in the XML of the .dtsx file where the "myemail@xxxx.com" value needs to be replaced.

```
<DTS:Variable
  DTS:CreationName=""
  DTS:DTSID="{F988AD8E-CCE3-4CC1-A447-2F7D3184577B}"
  DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
  DTS:Namespace="User"
  DTS:ObjectName="AlertEmail">
  <DTS:VariableValue
    DTS:DataType="8">myemail@xxxx.com</DTS:VariableValue>
</DTS:Variable>
```

I am hoping there is something similar to dtutil or dtexec that will recognize the specific XML child node for a specific variable in the .dtsx file and the update it, save the file so that it can then be easily copied to Integration Services with dtutil.  Otherwise, editing with custom code in the batch file may be the only option that performs an update on a block of three lines for each variable (applying above example).

```
  DTS:ObjectName="AlertEmail">
  <DTS:VariableValue
    DTS:DataType="8">myemail@xxxx.com</DTS:VariableValue>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to change the package here?  If so, you should read up on [Integration Services Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671628.aspx), which are designed for just this type of situation. Essentially, they allow you to separate the variable from the package, and each time the package runs it goes out to the (table, xml file, etc.) and populates the value from there.

Comment: If you are asking how to programmatically edit a package, have you looked into BiML?   I've never used it but I've heard good things about it.

Comment: Thank you for both suggestions and am testing them along with a third option to see which has the smallest footprint for the clients.  If I go with AHiggins's suggestion, it will likely need to apply an XML file for containing the configurations.  Sorry for the delay and thanks again.